# Is there a bash function for determining number of variables from a read provided from end user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

I am currently working on a small command line interface tool that someone not very familiar with bash could run from their computer. I have changed content for confidentiality, however functionality has remained the same.

The user would be given a prompt
the user would then respond with their answer(s)
From this, I would be given two bits of information:
1.their responses now as individual variables
2.the number of variables that I have now been given: this value is now a variable as well

my current script is as follows

```
echo List your favorite car manufacturers 
read $car1 $car2 $car3 #end user can list as many as they wish

for n in {1..$numberofmanufacturers} #finding the number of 
variables/manufactures is my second question

do
echo car$n
done
```

I am wanting to allow for the user to enter as many car manufacturers as they please (1=<n), however I need each manufacturer to be a different variable. I also need to be able to automate the count of the number of manufacturers and have that value be its own new variable.

Would I be better suited for having the end user create a .txt file in which they list (vertically) their manufactures, thus forcing me to use wc -l to determine the number of manufacturers?

I appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: Why do you "need each manufacturer to be a different variable"? Usually at this point one would recommend using an array — one variable with multiple values.

Comment: For later usage I was going to grep each variable through a list of .csv files using a for-loop that I have. Would I still be able to do that if they were to be values?

Comment: How do you distinguish items in the user's input? For instance, if they type in "Ford Mustang Geo Metro", is that two items or four?

Comment: @GordonDavisson for my purposes: I would want it to be 4 items.

Comment: (1) `read` does not read **variables**, it reads the user input **into** variables (breaking it into words). Hence **you** define the number of variables; it does not make sense to ask for how to determine the "number of variables". For variable length input, read into an array (for instance using `readarray` or  `mapfile` or `read -a`). (2) Your `read $car1` does not make sense. If `car1` is unset, the command is extended to a plain `read`, i.e. the the input is stored into the default variable `REPLY`.

Comment: Also, you can't use parameter expansion to create a brace expression, because the brace expression is evaluated before parameters are expanded. Use `for ((n=1; n <= $numberOfManufacturers; n++))` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, whenever you want to use multiple dynamically created variables, you should check if there isn't a better data structure for your use case; and in almost all cases there will be. Here is the implementation using bash arrays. It prints out the contents of the input array in three different ways.

```
echo List your favorite car manufacturers 
# read in an array, split on spaces
read -a cars


echo Looping over array values
for car in "${cars[@]}"
do
  echo $car
done

echo Looping over array indices
for i in ${!cars[@]}
do
  echo ${cars[$i]}
done

echo Looping from 0 to length-1
let numcars=${#cars[@]}
for i in $(seq 0 $((numcars-1)))
do
  echo ${cars[$i]}
done
```

Comment: This worked absolutely beautifully! Thank you so much @Amadan